# Redundant parameter after jQuery form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I want to rewrite form action URL upon form submission. I wrote a short Jquery code below. However, after submitting form, the URL is always like

```
/events/category/Red?cat=147003
```

The redundant **?cat=147003** causes HTTP 404 error.

How can I get a form action URL that is just

```
/events/category/Red (or)
/events/category/Blue
```

Thank you!

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="get">
  <select name="cat" id="cat" class="postform">     
     <option class="level-0" value="147003">Red</option>    
     <option class="level-0" value="147058">Blue</option> </select>
  <input value="Submit" class="colorFormSubmit" type="submit"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var formActionUrl="/events/category/";
  formActionUrl += jQuery("#form1 :selected").text();
  jQuery("#form1").attr('action', formActionUrl);
  //alert(formActionUrl);
});
</script>
```

Follow-up:

added
    jQuery(".postform").removeAttr('name');

and it works now.

Comment: Change your method to POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the name attribute from the select, it should prevent its value from being submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: Thank you. I added jQuery(".postform").removeAttr('name'); and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Change your form's method to POST (`<form method="POST">`). When using GET it will add all of the form fields to the URL when submitted. POST sends this information as part of the body of the message. Whatever server you are calling might need to change to expect the values from the new source.

Though, if you are not interested in passing values back then you could cancel the form submission entirely and simply redirect:

```
jQuery( "#form1" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var formActionUrl="/events/category/";
  formActionUrl += jQuery("#form1 :selected").text();
  window.location = formActionUrl;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Changed to POST but still did not work. I removed "name" attribute and it worked.